# Can't access command history in my shell (sh)

Tags: shell, debian, dash

I'm not sure if readline is what really missing but the problem is shell (instead of bash) and when I click the up and down arrow I get the following instead of command history:

```
$ ^[[A^[[A^[[A^[[A^[[A^[[A^[[A
```

What's missing?

Comment: What shell are you using?  Type `echo $0` to find out your shell.

Comment: probably proper setting of the TERM variable and maybe shell environment variables.  Check the man page for the specifics.

Comment: @unxnut $ echo $0 
-sh

Comment: What's missing? The way you started that shell, for a start. Did you log in on the console? Start a terminal in X? Log in via SSH? Does that always happen with this account, or only for certain ways of starting a shell? Did it always happen, and if not what changed?

Comment: I do not think `sh` supports command history.  That is why the arrows are getting echoed to the screen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are running `sh`, which in Debian links to `dash`. If that is not the shell you want, try typing in `exec bash`.

`dash` (well, neither `dash` nor the original Bourne `sh`) doesn't use readline, which explains why you see those escape sequences when you attempt to use the arrow keys.

Answer (score 0):

Install [the **`rlwrap`** util](https://github.com/hanslub42/rlwrap), and use it like so:

```
rlwrap dash
```

After which, pressing the <kbd>↑</kbd> will return the previous lines in the history, much like `bash`.